# Dynatrace visualizations for Micrometer metrics exported from Spring boot 2

Tags: spring-boot-actuator, micrometer, dynatrace, spring-micrometer

Export metrics to dynatrace using Micrometer.io
gradle dependency 'io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-dynatrace:latest.release' 
version - (1.1.3) 
Causing Exception -> Error {"error":{"code":400,"message":"Could not map JSON at 'series[33].dataPoints' near line 1 column 4071"}} {}

 `metrics:
      export:
        dynatrace:
          device-id: xxxxx
          uri: https://xxxx/e/xxxxx/api/v1/entity/infrastructure/custom
          api-token: xxxxxxx
          enabled: true
          technology-type: java
          step: 1m`

Comment: I would check HTTP status codes from sending the data to Dynatrace, an non 2xx code will indicate a problem. Then I would check in the "custom chart" if the metric is available.

Comment: @Centric thanks for your reply found the cause of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue with latest micrometer release(1.1.3). While forming Json data from the metrics its throwing exception i went one minor version(1.1.1) older it worked fine. Should open the bug for this.

Error
{"error":{"code":400,"message":"Could not map JSON at 'series[33].dataPoints' near line 1 column 4071"}} {}

We are getting this error while its trying to convert the CPU metrics to json